# Tinderbot is scraping only 1 Image instead of all

Tags: python, tinder

I am using a this tinderbot https://github.com/frederikme/TinderBotz
But the scraper is only scraping 1 Image per time. I also tried both ways, False and True but both versions are only scraping 1 image per profile, instead of all.

```
'''
Created by Frederikme (TeetiFM)
'''
import random, time
from tinderbotz.session import Session

if _name_ == "__main__":

    # creates instance of session
    session = Session()

    # set a custom location
    session.set_custom_location(latitude=51.509865, longitude=-0.118092)
    
    # replace this with your own email and password!
    email = "LOGIN"
    password = "PASS"
    
    # login using your google account with a verified email! Alternatively, you can use Facebook login
    session.login_using_facebook(email, password)

    # start scraping as much geomatches as possible
    while True:
        # When scraping we want ALL images and not just the first few.
        # If you want to scrape a lot quicker, I recommend putting quickload on True
        # But note that you'd only get 1-3 image urls instead of them all.
        geomatch = session.get_geomatch(quickload=False)

        # check if crucial data is not empty (This will rarely be the case tho, but we want a 'clean' dataset
        if geomatch.get_name() is not None \
                and geomatch.get_image_urls() != []:

            # let's store the data of the geomatch locally (this includes all images!)
            session.store_local(geomatch)

            # display the saved data on your console
            print(geomatch.get_dictionary())

            # account is scraped, now dislike and go next (since dislikes are infinite)
            # NOTE: if no amount is passed, it will dislike once -> same as => dislike(amount=1)
            # NOTE: if you have TinderPlus, -Gold or -Platinum you could also use session.like()
            session.dislike()

        else:
            # refresh webpage, and go for another geomatch
            session.browser.refresh()

        # make a random sleep between dislikes between 0 and 4 seconds to mimic looks human-like, not spammy behaviour
        sleepy_time = random.random() * 4
        time.sleep(sleepy_time)
```

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but according to [ToS](https://policies.tinder.com/terms/intl/en) "Service are automatically revoked in the event that you do . . . use any robot, bot, spider, crawler, scraper, site search/retrieval application, proxy or other manual or automatic device, method or process to access, retrieve, index, "data mine", or in any way reproduce or circumvent the navigational structure or presentation of the Service or its contents." Are you sure this is okay?

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, the library does not support all images, so it is just the Library issue, not you.

I just suggest two ways:

- Update the library that is installed on your OS

For example, if you are on Windows OS, you can find the installed library in `c:\users\*username*\appdata\local\programs\python\python*version*\lib\site-packages` directory.

- Just report the issue to development team, and after they updated the issue, you can re-install this library.

you just can report your issue on `https://github.com/frederikme/TinderBotz/issues/new/choose`.

Actually, I have no experience in TinderBotz library, so I can not tell you need to update which row in which file, how to update it....
But I wanted to suggested something for you.

Hope you make sense even a little.

Regards